# Is this a closed map?

Tags: continuity, closed-map

I'm reading the Munkres' "Topology", Section 22, Example 1.

> Example 1. Let $X$ be the subspace $[0,1]\cup[2,3]$ of $\mathbb R$, and let $Y$ be the subspace $[0,2]$ of $\mathbb R$.
>   The map $p:X\to Y$ defined by
>   $$p(x)=\begin{cases}x&\text{for }x\in[0,1]\\x-1&\text{for }x\in[2,3]\end{cases}$$
>   is readily seen to be surjective, continuous, and closed.

[the graph of p](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myuP5.png)(Why is it presented dim and black? I don't know)

Surjectivity is just trivial.

Continuity goes like this.
Consider an open interval $I$ in $Y=[0,2]$.
Suppose $I$ doesn't contain $1$, w.l.o.g, suppose $I\subset[0,1]$.
It follows from the monotonicity of p in [0,1] that $p^{-1}(I)$ is open.
Suppose not, i.e. $I$ contains $1$.
Then $p^{-1}(I)$ is an intersection of an open interval in $\mathbb R$ and $X$, thus $p^{-1}(I)$ is closed in $X$.

But I'm having difficulty in the problem of closedness of $p$.

Summary :

1. Does the *continuity* proof right?
2. How can I prove that $p$ is closed?

Comment: What have you tried in proving closedness?

Comment: I have to prove that if $C$ is closed in $X=[0,1]\cup[2,3]$, then so is $p(C)$. So I think I have to consider all the closed sets $C$. Thinking of $C$ as C=$X\setminus U$ for some open $U$ in $X$, or $C=C_0\cap X$ for some $C_0$ closed in $\mathbb R$ seems too complicated. I tried to find equivalent condition of $p$ being closed, but unsuccessfully, a couple of minutes earlier, since there was no indexed stuff in the book. Now I found one at wikipedia that $\overline{p(A)}\subset p(\bar A)$ for all $A\subset X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $C$ is  closed subset in $[0,1]\cup[2,3]$ then $C$ is the union of compact sets $C_1=C\cap[0,1]$ and $C_2=C\cap[2,3]$ and 
$$
p(C)=p(C_1)\cup p(C_2)=f(C_1)\cup h(C_2)$$
where $f:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$ is $f(x)=x$ and $h:[2,3]\rightarrow[1,2]$ is $h(x)=x-1$. Both functions are continuous and so $f(C_1)$ is compact subset (and hence closed) of $[0,1]$ and $h(C_2)$ is a compact subset (and hence closed) of $[1,2]$. This means that $p(C)$ is closed.

Comment: So the closedness follows from the continuity. Thanks a lot!